# how can i keep the link as it is before like the comment?

Tags: c#, asp.net

OK i understand that the question is not that specific but i will explain.
I work on a website that where people can vote about specific questions on what is important to them and they can also comment after they wrote their thoughts. the problem is, people can like the comments other people give, and I'm not talking about liking with Facebook, since people have to sing up to use the site, i've created a button and a function for liking. but once you have liked a comment you cannot like it again, and there's no unlike. and if you hit like again a msgbox shows up that tells you that you have already liked this. now the problem is that, if you like it once, the url of the site changes when the msgbox appears and when you even try to like something else, or try to vote, it shows the msgbox that "you have already liked this!"

Url before:
        http://www.somesite.com/home/boduvanje?opstina_id=35

Url after:
        http://www.somesite.com/home/boduvanje?opstina_id=35&odgovor_id=28

Sry about the long description but i thought more words would help.

Heres the like function:

```
    public ActionResult boduvanje(int opstina_id, int odgovor_id)
    {
        Session["id_momentalno"] = opstina_id;
        var ops = Convert.ToInt32(Session["id_momentalno"]);
        var log = Convert.ToInt32(Session["logiran"]);
        ViewData["log"] = log;


        if (log == 1 )
        {
            int users_id = mor.FindUser_IdByUserName(Session["userName"].ToString());
            if (mor.FindRezultatIdByUserId(users_id) & mor.FindRezultatIdByOdgovorId(odgovor_id))
            {
                Response.Write("<html><div id='msg1' onclick='message();'><div class='response' id='response_msg'>Веќе сте лајкнале! Немате право повторно !</div></div></html>");
                var lista = mor.FindAllData(opstina_id).ToList();
                return View("About", lista);


            }
            else
            {
                rezultati rez = new rezultati();
                rez.opstina_id = opstina_id;
                rez.odgovor_id = odgovor_id;
                int id = mor.FindUser_IdByUserName(Session["userName"].ToString());
                rez.user_id = id;
                mor.AddRezultati(rez);
                mor.Save();
                var lista = mor.FindAllData(opstina_id).ToList();
                return View("About", lista);
            }
        }
        else
        {

            Response.Write("<html><div id='msg1' onclick='message();'><div class='response' id='response_msg'>Не сте логирани !</div></div></html>");
            var lista = mor.FindAllData(opstina_id).ToList();
            return RedirectToAction("LogOn", "Account");

        }

    }
```

the code in the asp file where the button is, is the following:

```
    <div class="like_button" id= "like_button" ><a href="/home/boduvanje?opstina_id=<%:Session["opstina_id"]%>&odgovor_id=<%: tcm.odgovor_id %>"><img src="/images/btn_dopaga.png" alt="like" /></a></div>
```

thank you in advance and tell me if i should post some more info or something else  :)

Answer (score 0):

For implement this logic, you have to update the like status along with replayId in the database. On clicking on the button you can call a  webservice for the status of the like. Then you can give the message in the javascript. By using the webservice it willnot affect the performance also. You can take the track of every like status of all the answers and questions.

Keeping the status in the session is not a good idea.